# Convert four bytes to 32bit unsigned integer

Tags: php

I have a large binary buffer in PHP script, finding a specific position. I need to convert 4-byte value to 32bit integer.

```
$seg = hex2bin("AABBCC00010014AABBCC");
$findStart=3;
echo bin2hex($seg[$findStart+0]);
echo bin2hex($seg[$findStart+1]);
echo bin2hex($seg[$findStart+2]);
echo bin2hex($seg[$findStart+3]);

Prints:
00010014
```

I need to convert `seg[findStart+0 .. findStart+3]` to 32bit integer. How to do it in PHP script? This example is a decimal number 65556.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of [the `unpack` function](http://php.net/unpack), which takes a format string and extracts data from a binary string.

Looking at the list of format codes, and your example, I believe you want

> N:     unsigned long (always 32 bit, big endian byte order)

So it would look something like this:

```
$int = unpack('Nvalue', $seg, $findStart)['value'];
```

For compatibility with older versions of PHP (<7.1), you can emulate the offset argument by consuming a fixed number of bytes into an ignored variable:

```
$int = unpack("c{$findStart}ignore/Nvalue", $seg)['value'];
```

Comment: Wow what kind of black magic is this, first version did not work but compatibility version gives me correct length value from the binary buffer.

Comment: @Whome It originated in Perl, I believe, so definitely black magic. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ord()`](http://php.net/ord) to convert a single byte into an integer, then use the left shift and the bitwise-or operator.  The first byte you will shift 24 bits to the left, the second byte you will shift 16 bytes to the left, the third 8 bytes.

```
$a = ord($seg[$findStart+0]);
$b = ord($seg[$findStart+1]);
$c = ord($seg[$findStart+2]);
$d = ord($seg[$findStart+3]);

$newInt = ($a << 24) | ($b << 16) | ($c << 8) | $d;
```

Comment: I am bad at PHP so this must have a simple bug, this did not work. `$len = ($seg[$findStart+0]<<24) | ($seg[$findStart+1]<<16) | ($seg[$findStart+2]<<8) | ($seg[$findStart+3]);`

Comment: use hexdec() to get your individual byte values

Comment: I think the function you'd need here would be `ord()`, which unpacks a single byte string into an integer; the reverse is named `asc()`, but they actually have nothing to do with ASCII. https://3v4l.org/RlftP

Comment: Thanks, this "normal" programming trick also works now. `(ord($seg[$findStart+0])<<24) | (ord($seg[$findStart+1])<<16) | (ord($seg[$findStart+2])<<8) | ord($seg[$findStart+3]);`